# Who changed my function keys? F7 and F8 functions have been overwritten in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, function-keys

F7 now opens Thunderbird and F8 opens Firefox.  I don't know when this changed, but this overrides the functions for those keys in all programs (quick-save in games, insert date in my text editor).

The first thing I checked was mouse and keyboard drivers, but uninstalling them didn't change the behaviour.

I want to change the function keys back to their old behaviour.

Comment: It could be office 2010, I had the same problem after installing it. No luck yet in removing those unwanted shortcuts...

Comment: Usually the Windows Hotkey Explorer http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/ is a good tip for such things, but I have the same problem and it shows nothing. :-(

Comment: Some keyboards with an "fn" key support permanently switching the meaning of the Function keys and tend to replace them with the useless or harmful "fn" functions of the buttons instead, for reasons nobody ever managed to understand. Sometimes the toggle is "fn"+CapsLock. You can test if this is the issue by pressing fn+F8 and see if the expected function of F8 activates.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Start menu and look for the shortcut for Mozilla Firefox.  Right-click it and then at the bottom of the list select `Properties`.  You should hopefully see something like this window:

[image]

Where my `Shortcut Key` says `CTRL + ALT + SCROLL LOCK` you can click in that box and press the backspace key to delete the shortcut.

If the key is not assigned to the shortcut on the start menu you may also need to look at the desktop icons.

Comment: This is a nicely laid-ouit answer, but isn't the solution to my problem.