# Function key taken by another program, how to default it

Tags: windows-7, function-keys

Everytime I press the **F11** key it opens up a browser window with the same URL. This happens anywhere I press it and I need this key to have it's default behavior because I use it to program on Visual Studio (Windows 7).

Any ideas why this is happening and how to go back to default function keys?, I haven't installed anything that I remember can cause this behavior.

This is a standard Dell desktop key board, no multimedia keys, like this one:

[image]

Firing URL is `http://argos:8080/Login.jsp?jsessionid=55rh3obsahm9m`

seems like one of our company's internal addresses but IT guys say they have no idea about it.

I don't see any suspicious software that can be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Keyboard applet in Control Panel, as well as any other CP applet that looks as if it might be keyboard/input device-related, as well as your installed programs list. There must be *something* extraneous that's causing this, since it's not default Windows behaviour. Also, what's the URL? Maybe that'll help track the software down.

Comment: hey @Karan, see my question update

Comment: Yeah, knowing the URL didn't help (it probably refers to an installation of [this](http://www.evisions.com/Products/ArgosEnterpriseReporting/Overview.aspx) on your intranet). What about Control Panel and your Add/Remove Programs list? Did you check those to see what 3rd party software is installed? Because *something* is and that's what is setting a global hotkey for F11. BTW, can you also check what your browser's home page is set to? It's possible the key is simply calling up your browser, which in turn is opening up its home page URL.

Comment: No home page on my browser but you were absolutely right I checked my programs list and sorted it by installation date, then I noticed IT guys installed me Microsoft RichCopy the last week, remove it and I got back my F11 key, thanks for insisting @Karan

Comment: You're welcome, glad you figured it out. BTW, RichCopy *should* have an option to de-register any global hotkeys it sets, but I'm not sure. Just something to look into if you ever do need it to be re-installed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you got an FN-toggle button on your keyboard? This sounds like you have one of the media keyboards with Mail and such bound to alternative uses of the Function keys.

Try hitting that button, if you have it, and if that is the problem it will be sorted.

Comment: Hey note that on some keyboards you have to hold the button for default behavior while on other keyboards that button can toggle between normal and shortcut behavior.

Comment: Ouch, I've not encountered that kind of keyboard. I guess it's not targeted at me, it just sounds bad for my usage.

Comment: nope, this is a standard desktop keyboard, FN-toggle button

Comment: Hm, okay. Thanks for image / response.

Comment: In this case I guess that this is a software problem. Do you have any Hotkey software or driver installed?

Comment: no hotkey software that I'm aware of, this is my office's pc and I keep it with the minimum stuff, by the way thanks @Jeeva and Itehnological for your interest

Comment: No worries. I don't suppose you're using a Logitech mouse and have Setpoint (or some equivalent) installed? Apologies for the questions I'm fairly sure the answers will be no to. Otherwise, have you tried the stuff posted [here](http://superuser.com/questions/334047/who-changed-my-function-keys-f7-and-f8-functions-have-been-overwritten-in-windo?rq=1)? Specifically the application that shows hotkeys, and checking to see if your browser has a shortcut key programmed.